# How to create a custom control which is a combobox with group header

Tags: wpf, combobox, custom-controls

I have a special requirement which need to implement a combobox which list data in groups and I could do it as below

the XAML file

```
<Window x:Class="GroupComboBox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
            <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" Width="100">

                <ComboBox.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="150" Height="Auto" >
                                        <!-- add scroll bar -->
                                    </WrapPanel>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="50" />
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.Resources>

                <ComboBox.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="YellowGreen"/>
                                </Border>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </ComboBox.GroupStyle>

                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item}" Width="40"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>



                <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Available}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ComboBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code-behind file

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<CategoryItem<string>> items = new List<CategoryItem<string>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 18; ++i)
            {
                items.Add(new CategoryItem<string> { Item = string.Format("{0:D2}", i), Available = (i > 9), Category = "Group A" });
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
            {
                items.Add(new CategoryItem<string> { Item = string.Format("{0:D2}", i), Available = (i > 2), Category = "Group B" });
            }

            //Need the list to be ordered by the category or you might get repeating categories
            ListCollectionView lcv = new ListCollectionView(items.OrderBy(w => w.Category).ToList());

            //Create a group description
            lcv.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Category"));

            this.comboBox.ItemsSource = lcv;

        }   

    }

    public class CategoryItem<T>
    {
        public T Item { get; set; }
        public bool Available { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I want to make the combobox to be a custom control, then it can be reused easily, but I am new for creating custom control and how should I do?

Currently I have created a WPF custom control library and change the base class of the custom control to be 'ComboBox' , but I do not know how to move the styles and templates to the resource dictionary file correctly

Comment: For your control set the style: `<Style x:Key="MyTemplateForMyControl" TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}"> ... <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">` - it you want?

Comment: @Anatoliy  What I want is a custom control which could be reused very easily (like the Button control in wpf toolbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can offer the following variant. Move all the styles and templates in *resources*:

```
<!-- Main style for ComboBox -->
<Style x:Key="MyComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />

    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
             <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                 <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="150" Height="Auto" />
             </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>

     <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
         <Setter.Value>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item}" Width="40"/>
             </DataTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>            
</Style>

<!-- Style for ComboBoxItem -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="50" />
</Style>

<!-- Style for ItemContainerStyle -->
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Available}" />
</Style>

<!-- DataTemplate for HeaderTemplate -->
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyHeaderTemplate">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="YellowGreen" />
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Using of ComboBox with our styles:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox1" Style="{StaticResource MyComboBox}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemContainerStyle}">
    <ComboBox.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MyHeaderTemplate}" />
    </ComboBox.GroupStyle>
</ComboBox>

<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox2" Style="{StaticResource MyComboBox}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemContainerStyle}">
    <ComboBox.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MyHeaderTemplate}" />
    </ComboBox.GroupStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

And set the data in code:

```
this.MyComboBox1.ItemsSource = lcv;
this.MyComboBox2.ItemsSource = lcv;
```

Set styles for you control need to change *Type* and write your control name:

```
<Style x:Key="MyControlComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControlComboBox}">

</Style>
```

Comment: although it is not using the custom control approach, but anyway it works, thanks :-)